# Device Token not shown when want to provide PushNotifications

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

i followed this Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3YlqWWnI6s
to provide PushNotifications in my App.
BTW: My App is a WebApp based on Cordova, (there's also an AdService called Flurry included).

Everything worked fine, i built the certificates and profile, added this to Xcode, i started my App and it asked me to allow PushNotifications. i said YES but it did not show the DeviceToken in the console. so what did i wrong? it even does not call the `didFinishedLaunchingWithOptions:` method

Here is my code in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
#endif
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
#else
        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];


    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    //Start the Flyuury Session
    [Flurry startSession:@"#######################"];

    // Pointer to the rootViewController. Note: the initialize call should be
    // invoked only once immediately after the call to startSession
    [FlurryAds initialize:window.rootViewController];

    return YES;
}
```

and the Method when it did register:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    NSLog(@"Dev Token: %@", deviceTokenString);

}
```

any help would be great.

EDIT:
Here's the console log:

```
2014-08-06 16:33:03.004 UnserTeam[2066:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-08-06 16:33:03.062 UnserTeam[2066:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-08-06 16:33:03.246 UnserTeam[2066:60b] [CDVTimer][file] 9.999990ms
2014-08-06 16:33:03.251 UnserTeam[2066:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 14.897048ms
2014-08-06 16:33:03.483 UnserTeam[2066:60b] Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_136_5.0.0] 
2014-08-06 16:33:03.660 UnserTeam[2066:60b] active
2014-08-06 16:33:04.834 UnserTeam[2066:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-08-06 16:33:05.494 UnserTeam[2066:500f] 13 entries in the zip file
2014-08-06 16:33:07.904 UnserTeam[2066:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Device'] took '13.353027' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

The last line is most interesting i think.

Comment: btw: it does not ask me to allow Notifications again, even if I delete the App

Comment: add this code - `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}` and see what error you get.

Comment: i implemented this method but it's not getting called. what can i do now. I think the App must ask me again to allow push notifications but is does not, it only asked me once

Comment: I made a native iosApp now and registered it for PushNotifications, and it worked. So it seems that there is a problem with Phonegap/Cordova, does anyone has experience with that?